# Remove Dictionary VALUE when value is of type Array

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary which is of:

var myDictionary: [String: [String]]

It has within it a list of items, and the KEY is the start of the items letter (similar to a contact list) and the value is a String array.

```
myDictionary = [String: [String]] = [ "a": [
                "Ace", "Aemc", "Allegro", "Ames", "Amprobe", "Anvil", "Appion", "Apple", "Arrow"
            ],
            "b": [
                "Bacharach", "Bauer", "Big Tex", "Black & Decker", "BMW", "Bobcat", "Bosch", "Bostitch", "Brady", "Briggs & Stratton", "Brother", "Burndy"
            ]
    ]
```

Similar to a search, I want to be able to find an item in the VALUES array but if it does exist, I want to REMOVE it from the dictionary.  Meaning, in the above, I want to be able to return a new dictionary WITHOUT that item.

So as an examples, from the code above, if I were to type in ACE, I would like to return a new Dictionary [String: [String]] WITHOUT 'Ace' in it.

Now I am able to iterate on the items found via:

```
for items in myDictionary where items.value.contains("Ace")
```

But I cannot find a way to remove just this one Value entry.

All searches I have found only show either removing the entire dictionary entry (removing via the key) but not an actual item from the Value.

Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thx

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has too many all-caps words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the item in place

1. Get the first letter of the query lowercased.
2. Check if the array at given key exists and get the index of the query if available
3. Remove the item at index

---

```
var myDictionary : [String: [String]] = [ "a": [
    "Ace", "Aemc", "Allegro", "Ames", "Amprobe", "Anvil", "Appion", "Apple", "Arrow"
],"b": [
    "Bacharach", "Bauer", "Big Tex", "Black & Decker", "BMW", "Bobcat", "Bosch", "Bostitch", "Brady", "Briggs & Stratton", "Brother", "Burndy"
]]

let query = "Ace"
let indexLetter = String(query.prefix(1).lowercased())
if let value = myDictionary[indexLetter], let index = value.firstIndex(of: query) {
    myDictionary[indexLetter]!.remove(at: index)
}
```